# Different way of implementing my reHash() algorithm

Tags: java

I'm implementing a hash table without the use of any built-in java HashTable features, and getting a compile-time error with the line:

```
newHashTable.add(reHashValueIndex, bucket.get(j));//insert values into new table
```

ERROR: no suitable method found for add(int, String)

I get that a String is not the same type as an ArrayList of LinkedLists of type String, which is why I'm getting the error, but I could use some assistance as to another way to possibly implement reHash()

```
public void reHash(ArrayList<LinkedList<String>> oldHashTable)
{
    ArrayList<LinkedList<String>> newHashTable = new ArrayList(oldHashTable.size()*2);

    //rehash values in oldHashTable
    for (int i = 0; i < (oldHashTable.size()); i++)//loop old hashTable.size number of times 
    {
        bucket = oldHashTable.get(i);//bucket = linkedList at oldHashTable
        if (bucket != null)//if hashTable linkedList bucket element contains elements 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bucket.size(); j++)//loop through it 
            {
                if(bucket.get(j) != null)//looking for items
                {
                    int reHashValueIndex = hash(bucket.get(j)); //rehash element 
                    newHashTable.add(reHashValueIndex, bucket.get(j));//insert values into new table at new rehashed index
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //increment expand variable by one
    expand++;
}
```

Comment: Once you rehash the jth string in your ith bucket, shouldn't you be getting the bucket at rehashValueIndex for newHashTable and adding the string to it? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

newHashTable is of type ArrayList <'LinkedList<'String>>.  so you can only add objects that are LinkedList.  What you probably want to do is first rebuild your bucket, and then add it to your newHashTable. something like this

```
    public void reHash(ArrayList<LinkedList<String>> oldHashTable)
    {
        ArrayList<LinkedList<String>> newHashTable = new ArrayList(oldHashTable.size()*2);

        //rehash values in oldHashTable
        for (int i = 0; i < (oldHashTable.size()); i++)//loop old hashTable.size number of times 
        {
            bucket = oldHashTable.get(i);//bucket = linkedList at oldHashTable

            if (bucket != null)//if hashTable linkedList bucket element contains elements 

            {
                newBucket = new LinkedList<String>();
                for (int j = 0; j < bucket.size(); j++)//loop through it 
                {
                    if(bucket.get(j) != null)//looking for items
                    {
                        int reHashValueIndex = hash(bucket.get(j)); //rehash element 
                        newBucket.add(reHashValueIndex, bucket.get(j));//insert values into new table at new rehashed index
                    }
                }
            }
            newHashTable.add(newBucket);
        }
        //increment expand variable by one
        expand++;
    }
```

Comment: I think the reHashValueIndex pertains to the newHashTable and not the newBucket ...moreover, when you try to add an element to an empty LinkedList at a particular non-zero index, it will throw an IndexOutOfBounds exception

Comment: Wow, don't know how I missed that. I was trying to insert Strings when I needed to insert buckets. I created a new bucket for every element in the old hashTable, and then added that to the reHashed index in the new table. I need to play around with it some more but thank you!!.